# cannot debugg vNext web app in vs 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I cannot debugg Asp.Net 5 project in my Visual Studio 2015. First when I open app I get message box with information:

> Cannot find DNX SD version 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta3'.....'dnx=clr-win-x86.1.0.0-bet5' will be used as the solution DNX SDK version for this session.

Then when I click Start to debbug app I get alert box:

> The debugger cannot continue running the process.Unable to start debugging.

Even when I create new project -> Asp.Net 5 preview template -> web application the behavior is the same. When I was using CTP version of VS 2015 everything worked but I had to change to VS 2015. I also cheked PowerShell version and it's 4.0.

I have no Idea what could be the reason. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install the correct DNVM,
you can read about it [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html).
Or change versions of packages that you use.
Put in cmd:

```
dnvm list
```

look what SDK version is default and then set in global.json and project.json same version.